# Loopback XML body data validation error problem

Tags: xml, loopbackjs, body-parser

I want to accept and save XML data through the model REST api. When I select "Parameter content type" and "Response Content Type"  "application/xml" or "text/xml", I got following validation error.

```
   <error>
    <statusCode>422</statusCode>
    <name>ValidationError</name>
    <message>The `testmodel` instance is not valid. 
             Details: `type` can't be blank (value: undefined); 
             `metric` can't be blank (value: undefined); 
             `valid` can't be blank (value: undefined); 
             `registerDate` can't be blank (value: undefined).
    </message>
    .....
   </error>
```

And my post data is

```
<testmodel>
    <type>testType</type>
    <metric>testMetric</metric>
    <valid>true</valid>
    <registerDate>Thu Jan 17 2019 10:25:59</registerDate>
</testmodel>
```

It works when selecting Parameter content type" and "Response Content Type" as JSON.

I set remoting.rest.xml to true under config.json file. Responses are okay with XML but post and put payload does not excepted due to validation error. 
I also added

```
"parse": {
    "express-xml-bodyparser": {"params": { "limit": "1024kb" }}
},
```

to middleware.json file but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some work I ended up with solution. Just put or change the below code at **middleware.json** file

```
"parse": {
    "express-xml-bodyparser": {"params": { "explicitArray": false , "explicitRoot":  false}}
},
```